# what is the right selector for this jQuery function? or $("#myElement")[0].href vs $("#myElement").href

Tags: jquery

please see: http://jsfiddle.net/4Z4fQ/19/

consider the following html:

```
<a id="myElement" href="http://www.google.com/">
    <img id="image"  src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="google"/>
</a>
```

and the following script:

```
jQuery.fn.MyFunction = function (event) {
   alert('My function was called');
   alert(this.href);
};


$("#myElement").click(function (event) {
   //some processing

   $("#myElement").MyFunction(event);
});
```

without changing MyFunction, how do I change this line: `$("#myElement").MyFunction(event);` so I get the href to show in the alert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Description

The selector is right. But you must call jQuery's `.attr()` function to get the `href` attribute because `this` is a jQuery Object.

#### Sample

```
jQuery.fn.MyFunction = function (event) {
   alert('My function was called');
   alert(this.attr("href"));
};
```

#### More Information

- **[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Z4fQ/21/)**
- [jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

there is no api as `href` in JQuery, make use of `attr` in `JQuery` to get value of any attribute in element.

```
alert($(this).attr("href"));
```